# Displaying the result in the page in Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to extract data from database (Arangodb) and display it on the page or even push it to next page. As of now I am able to display the data in console by clicking button. But I just want to display the output in the angular page itself not in the console.

How can I fix this?

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'app';
constructor(private http: Http) {}

server_wsdl_get(){
return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
.map((res: Response) => res.json())
}

 client_wsdl_get() {
   this.server_wsdl_get().subscribe(data => {
   console.log(data);
   this.data = data;
   })
 }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<li>
 <button type="submit" (click)="client_wsdl_get()">test GET data</button>
</li>
```

I want this result to be displayed in the angular page not in the console.

[image]

Comment: You are getting a JSON so probably is not what you want to print in template. But the same way you are using the http response to console.log the response use that to create the template you want. Nobody here knows how do you want to print the data

Comment: what does your client_wsdl_get() function look like? can you add it to the question please?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do but Angular comes with a JSON pipe https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe

Comment: I'd suggest working through a tutorial to learn the basics of binding and data access. You can work through the tutorial here: https://angular.io/tutorial

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Hi..,I have added the details again

Comment: Questions that ask "please help me" tend to be looking for highly localized guidance, or in some cases, ongoing or private assistance, which is not suited to our Q&A format. It is also rather vague, and is better replaced with a more specific question. Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be accurate, you have to declare your class field before using it (`this.data`):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  data: any;
  title = 'app';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  server_wsdl_get() {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

  client_wsdl_get() {
    this.server_wsdl_get().subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.data = data;
    })
  }
}
```

Now in template you can display your data with:

```
<span>{{data?.type}}</span>
```

Operator `?.` ensures that there will be no error when `data` is not defined yet (when you want to get a property of undefined you get `TypeError: Cannot read property '' of undefined`). Other way of solving this problem is providing a default data values or using `*ngIf.`

Comment: this doesnt work..,still i am getting the result in console.

Comment: @yuvii_10 I think you don't know what you are doing. Please go through https://angular.io/tutorial